# Inexplicable error with left_joins with large data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I've been stuck on this issue for a while now and really don't know what to do anymore:

I am trying to do a left_join in order to join my main data frame with another data-structure (which I will refer to as the "helper structure", of the same number of rows) that I use to build a set of rates of change for variables included in the main data frame.

What I do is the following: I have written a script that builds the helper structure, in which I only need to specify the variable (in the mainframe) for which I want to build the rates of change.

The script ends with a left_join (of the helper structure and the main data frame based on the IDs of observations, which both frames share) and then removes the helper structure. I then replace in the script the name of the variable with the name of the next variable I want to build my rates of change for and rerun the script.

Here's the problem: when I run the script with a first variable, everything works like a charm. The rates of change for the specified variable are added to the mainframe as new variables and the helper structure is removed. However, when I now replace the name of the variable with the next variable for which to build the rates of change, I get the following error at the point of the left_join.

```
Error in left_join_impl(x, y, by_x, by_y, aux_x, aux_y, na_matches) :
std::bad_alloc r
```

This error appears no matter which variable-name I replace the first one by - AND: even when I rerun the script with the same variable name.

I really don't know what to do.

Comment: I should add that I've successfully used this procedure on another sample.

Comment: Would be great to add sample code and data.

Comment: Also, try running in RStudio and in R only.

Comment: Have you tried left joining with base R? Something like `merge(df1, df2, by = "id", all.x = TRUE)`

Comment: I just tried the merge-function but when I run it I get the following error: "Error in merge.data.frame( ),  :   negative length vectors are not allowed". From reading up on a couple of google-findings, this error appears the number of rows exceeds 2^31-1, which shouldn't be true in my case (joining two data frames of the same length with about 270k observations. Please help! :(